# XML Parsing Query to filter multiple data from XML

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have XML with sample data as below:

```
<result command="searchhotels" date="2018-07-12 11:34:48" elapsedTime="0.12741708755493" ip="178.63.96.219" tID="1531395288103187" version="4.0">
<hotels>
<hotel hotelid="53754">
<rooms>
<room adults="2" children="0" extrabeds="0">
<roomType roomtypecode="59776945">
```

I need to obtain list of all hotelid by using XPath in Postgres.

Any relevant query/approach would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Is it hard to post well formed sample data? it's annoying when you most spend some minutes to figure out and fix that example to test a solution for you.

```
select   xpath ('//hotel/@hotelid', your_xml)
```

will return an array of attribute "hotelid" values from all "hotel" elements

you can get more data out from that xml for example

```
with mytable as (select 
'
<result command="searchhotels" date="2018-07-12 11:34:48" elapsedTime="0.12741708755493" ip="178.63.96.219" tID="1531395288103187" version="4.0">
   <hotels>
      <hotel hotelid="53754">
         <rooms>
            <room adults="2" children="0" extrabeds="0">
               <roomType roomtypecode="59776945" />
            </room>
            <room adults="4" children="0" extrabeds="0">
               <roomType roomtypecode="59745" />
            </room>
         </rooms>
      </hotel>
      <hotel hotelid="53756">
         <rooms>
            <room adults="2" children="2" extrabeds="2">
               <roomType roomtypecode="59776949" />
            </room>
         </rooms>
      </hotel>
   </hotels>
</result>
'::xml some_xml
)
,v1 as (select unnest(zz) zz from (select   xpath ('//hotel', some_xml)zz from mytable)q1)
,v2 as (select (xpath ('//hotel/@hotelid', zz))[1] as hotelid , zz  from v1)
,v3 as (select hotelid, unnest(zz) zz from ( select hotelid, xpath ('//room', zz) zz from v2)q1)
select hotelid
       , (xpath ('//room/@adults', zz))[1] adults
       , (xpath ('//room/@children', zz))[1] as children
       , (xpath ('//room/@extrabeds', zz))[1] as extrabeds 
       , (xpath ('//room/roomType/@roomtypecode', zz))[1] as roomtypecode  
  from v3
```

will result in

```
hotelid|adults|children|extrabeds|roomtypecode
53754  |2     |0       |0        |59776945
53754  |4     |0       |0        |59745
53756  |2     |2       |2        |59776949
```

Comment: Sorry for unformatted data & will remember henceforth..Thanks for the soluion

Comment: @VinitShetye If this did work for you, it would be nice from you to close this thread and  pick an answer or answer with a better solution yourself. Have a nice day :D